# How to retrieve the database values to jquery auto complete box through php page

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql

I am a newbie to jQuery; I want to get the data from a database to auto-complete a text box.

I have coded the PHP to get the values from the database. How can I get these PHP values in a jQuery page?

This is the script:

```
 <script>
    $(function() {
        var Theaters = [
            "PVR",
            "SCR",
            "MTR"
        ];
        $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
            source: Theaters
        });
    });
    </script>
```

This is the PHP page:

```
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost", "root") or die (mysql_error ());
mysql_select_db("theaterdb") or die(mysql_error());
$strSQL = "SELECT * FROM theaters";
$rs = mysql_query($strSQL);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs)) 
{
echo $row['theater_name'] . "<br />";
 }
mysql_close();
?>
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use ajax for this purpose.

```
<html>
 <head>
 <title>Untitled Document</title>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
 $(function(){
    $('#radioid').click(function() {
    $('#txtDoorStyle').val($(this).val());
});
 });
 </script>
  </head>
 <body>
 <input type="radio" id="radioid" value="Door Half Transom (011)" name="doorstyle">
 <input type="text" value="" id="txtDoorStyle" name="txtDoorStyle" >
 </body>
 </html>>
```

Answer (score 0):

you have two choices either two load this autocomplete options upfront in which case you store the data that you have retrieved from the dB in a hidden field after serializing the data to a string and in your javascript you parse it back to an array using `str.split(",")`

or

you could make an ajax request when the user starts typing and then retrieve the data as a string and then parse it to an array and then pass it to the autoComplete api. You can read about jquery ajax [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax)